# LWJGL- Quad translates and then returns to its old position

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Currently what happens is that whenever I press Space it translates and then returns to its previous position. How do I make it so that after it translates it remains in that spot and then after you click space again it moves again and doesn't remain in the previous position? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
public void renderchar() {
    glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_NORMALIZE);

    keypress();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    {
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100,100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+character.getTextureWidth(),100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+character.getTextureWidth(),100+character.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100,100+character.getTextureHeight());
    }

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2);

    while(Keyboard.next()) {
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
            System.out.println("SPACE KEY IS DOWN");
            GL11.glTranslatef(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    glPopMatrix();

    GL11.glEnd(); 
    if (totalTime > 500) {
    }
}

public void keypress() {
    while(Keyboard.next()) {
        if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_SPACE) {
            GL11.glTranslatef(100,0,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats happening is when you press space, it translates the object, and the next time it runs through, if your space key isn't pressed, it won't do the translation. The glTranslatef isn't incrementive if the matrix is popped, so you need an external variable to store the amount the object is translated.

```
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
float z = 0.0f;
GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
while(Keyboard.next()) {
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
        System.out.println("SPACE KEY IS DOWN");
        x += 1.0f;
        y += 1.0f;
        z += 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: "The glTranslatef isn't incrementive" That's not exactly true. You can call `glTranslatef` multiple times, and their effects stack. But since you called `glPopMatrix`, the matrix that `glTranslatef` affected gets deleted, and so did the translation.